# Finding untraced time in Google Cloud Tracer Agent for Express.js

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-trace

I'm using Google Cloud's [Stackdriver Trace Agent](https://github.com/googleapis/cloud-trace-nodejs) with the Express.js plugin.

I noticed there are a few routes which have substantial "untraced" time. What strategies can I use to find and begin to measure these untraced paths, and why would it not pick up certain code paths?

Answer (score 0):

If the Trace agent isn't working, there's unfortunately not very much you can do to modify its behavior.  I recommend using [OpenCensus](https://opencensus.io/quickstart/nodejs/tracing/) to instrument your application, which will give you much more control over exactly how traces and spans are created.